# Not all elements stay in place when the screen expands and shrinks

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the black triangle stay in place when the screen expands and shrinks. The yellow and black pieces stay but I can't figure out why the red ones won't. It is supposed to be in the shape of a crown but I have the triangles red and black so I can see them.

```css
.yellow {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.triangle1 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}

.triangle2 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid black;
  position: relative;
  left: 32%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="crown.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="triangle1"></div>
  <div class="triangle2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Its because you have `left: 32%` but it sounds like you want a set number of pixels for it to stay in a static place. Try `left: 200px;` instead

Answer (score 0):

The second elements has `position:` relative;`. It moves left 32% relative to the browser window. You can use` position: `absolute;` instead and use a fixed left position, e.g. 200px.

```css
.yellow {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.triangle1 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}

.triangle2 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="crown.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="triangle1"></div>
  <div class="triangle2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have, you're close but I would make the .yellow div a parent container of the two triangles. Change the position to relative and then position the children absolute inside that parent.

```css
.yellow {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;

.triangle1 {
  width: 0;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
}

.triangle2 {
  width: 0;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <a href="index.html">back</a>
    <h1>crown</h1>  
  </main>

  <div class="yellow">
    <div class="triangle1"></div>
    <div class="triangle2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

OR

You can add a clip-path to the parent and remove the two children.

```css
.yellow {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 38%, 50% 0%, 75% 38%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%);
```